# Specify mount point for Samba share

Tags: catalina, smb

I can connect to a Samba share on my Raspberry Pi with the following:-

```
open smb://pi:password@MilliwaysPi4.local/pi
```

This works, and Finder shows the Location as MilliwaysPi4.local with access to the pi home directory.

This mounts at `/Volumes/pi` but if I have another Raspberry Pi already mounted it mounts at `/Volumes/pi-1` etc.

Is there any way I can specify a mount point?

On Linux I can mount a share on my Mac at a specified mount point `/mnt/Image` with a command like the following:-

```
sudo mount.cifs //Milliways.local/Images /mnt/Image -o user=XXX
```

Is there any similar option in macOS.
The Help file is very brief, and I can't find any detailed documentation for the open smb:// commands.

Comment: Did you try `man mount` or `man mount_smbfs`? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `open smb://` command is just automating what you're doing manually in Linux

Start by creating the mount point

```
sudo mkdir /Volumes/foobar
```

Then mount the share

```
sudo mount -t smbfs //user@hostname/path/to/share /Volumes/foobar
```

or

```
sudo mount_smbfs //user@hostname/path/to/share /Volumes/foobar
```